# Error 301 when try to upload a file from my flutter app to my web server

Tags: flutter

I´m working my first project in flutter. I have a web server with mysql, and I'm sedind there the data. I have an upload folder in my public_html folder.

In flutter, I take a photo and I want upload that file to my upload folder in the server, and keep the address to that file in mysql.

I need to send the file (jpg) to the server. I find several explanations about how to do it, I wrote the code, but now it give me a 301 error and I don´t understand why.

I check the path of the file, and it looks fine. 
I put the path that I provided for the Uri in my google and it show me the folder where I want to copy the file.

```
    Future uploadFile() async {
    var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(_image.openRead()));
    var length = await _image.length();

    var uri = Uri.parse("http://www.teknopartner.cl/uploads");

    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length,
        filename: basename(_image.path));

    request.files.add(multipartFile);
    var response = await request.send();
    print("listo " + response.statusCode.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi is an error with your URI. If you try to make a request in cURL you get:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 08 Oct 2019 17:28:11 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.teknopartner.cl/uploads/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

If you see the Location that indicates where has been move you get a / in the end if you change the URI to http://www.teknopartner.cl/uploads/ it should work fine.

Comment: I try this, but when I write the url in this way, it give me another error (a worst error if that make sense), statuscode 404

Comment: I was thinking if it could be a security error, maybe I need to change something in my server to let some external app upload any file?

Comment: When I do a curl -I http://www.teknopartner.cl/uploads/ I get a 200 OK response. You have to check your code. It could be a problem with your directory permission also. Check your server logs to see what is happening.

Comment: I had the same issue, this fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: missing the trailing / returns a 301 status code

Answer (score 4):

If your url expecting **https** request rather than **http** request than you will get this error.

**change**

`final uri = Uri.http(url, path,query);`

**to**

`final uri = Uri.https(url, path,query);`

**This will solve this issue most of the time.**